# TypeScript Type Annotation Excluding Primitives

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

**The question:**
Is there any way to write a type annotation in TypeScript that allows any object literal, but doesn't allow built-in types `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `Function` or `Array`?

**Why?**

I have been working on improving some type definitions on DefinitelyTyped for some libraries I am using on my projects at work.  A common pattern I have noticed in many JS libraries is to pass an 'options' object used to configure the library or plugin.  In these cases, you will often you will see type definitions looking something like this:

```
declare module 'myModule' {
    interface IMyModule {
        (opts?: IOptions): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
    }
    interface IOptions {
        callback?: Function;
        readonly?: boolean;
    }
}
```

This allows you to use it like this:

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
myModule();
myModule({});
myModule({ callback: () => {} });
myModule({ readonly: false });
myModule({ callback: () => {}, readonly: false });
```

Which all are valid use cases.  The trouble is that these type definitions also allow for these non-valid use cases:

```
myModule('hello');
myModule(false);
myModule(42);
myModule(() => {});
myModule([]);
```

In many cases, the above calls would result in a runtime error, as the library JS code may try to set default values on the object, or pass the options to another library.  Although I have tried many things, I haven't been able to constrain the parameter to accept only objects and not any of those other invalid cases.

It seems that if you have an interface with only optional members (as no one option is required), the compiler will widen acceptable types to accept `any`.

You can see a TypeScript Playground demonstration of this problem here: http://bit.ly/1Js7tLr

**Update: An example of a solution that doesn't work**

```
interface IOptions {
    [name: string]: any;
    callback?: Function;
    readonly?: boolean;
}
```

This attempt requires an indexing operator to be present on the object, which means that it now complains about `number`s, `string`s, `boolean`s, `Function`s, and `Array`s.  But this creates a new problem:

```
var opts = {};
myModule(opts);
```

This now fails when it should be a valid scenario. (See this in Playground: http://bit.ly/1MPbxfX)

Comment: I have seen this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3823, but I'm not sure if this solves this issue or not, and it is v1.6.  I would love to find a way to accomplish this in 1.5 if possible.

Comment: You would likely need to just run a lot of checks, nothing elegant I imagine. All of these cases might help you: http://tobyho.com/2011/01/28/checking-types-in-javascript/

Comment: @ZacharyDow, here I am not actually writing a JavaScript library, but instead writing TypeScript type definitions that describe the API of an existing JavaScript library (see https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).  I have no control over the code that will ultimately be called.  My objective is to help TypeScript users to get compile errors if they pass the wrong types as options, so they don't falsely assume it will work just because it compiles.  Without these compile-time errors, the users cannot have confidence that the definitions are correct or useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of TypeScript 2.2, there is now an `object` type that does almost exactly what I have described above.

> ... you can assign anything to the `object` type except for `string`, `boolean`, `number`, `symbol`, and, when using `strictNullChecks`, `null` and `undefined`.

Check out the official announcement here: [Announcing TypeScript 2.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/02/22/announcing-typescript-2-2/)

Answer (score 1):

For an interface to have sensible enforcement, it must have at least one mandatory member. Essentially, the interface below enforces nothing:

```
interface IOptions {
    callback?: Function;
    readonly?: boolean;
}
```

It is actually equivalent to the "evil interface":

```
interface IOptions {
}
```

So you are getting auto-completion, but no real type checking.

Your proposed solution is the way to go...

```
interface IOptions {
    [name: string]: any;
    callback?: Function;
    readonly?: boolean;
}
```

In most cases, people tend to construct these options within the function call, but if they really want to do it elsewhere they can use a type assertion:

```
// If you must
var opts = <IOptions>{};
myModule(opts);

// More typical
myModule({});

// Although... if its empty
myModule();
```

Disclaimer. A small part of this is just my opinion... but an empty interface is the worst thing you can do with an interface in TypeScript and one that enforces nothing is the second-worst thing.

You could avoid the duplication using your own base interface...

```
interface Indexed {
    [name: string]: any;
}
```

Or even...

```
interface Indexed<T> {
    [name: string]: T;
}
```

And then use it on all your options interfaces...

```
interface IOptions extends Indexed {
    callback?: Function;
    readonly?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: I think you are right, although I personally would prefer `var opts: IOptions = {};` to `var opts = <IOptions>{};`
I see these 'empty interfaces' all over DefinitelyTyped, and as I go through test files I see things that pass compilation but would most definitely not work.  I was hoping there was a better way, it seems like having to add the indexer to each 'options' interface is less than optimally elegant.
Thanks for confirming this.

Comment: If only there was a built-in interface that contained the default indexer, you could extend that in your interface and get the correct behavior by default.

Comment: I have added the base class in simple and generic form if you want to include it in your definitions :)