# Typescript type for unknown object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to delcare a Javascript object in typescript but i don't know what will be inside.

I currently use `any` but my object can be of type `null`, `undefined`, `boolean`, ...

I would like to be sure that my object is a Javascript object even if it is empty (`{}`)

Comment: anymore information for the object you are using?

Comment: `object` is most likely what you want. However, if you are going to use some specific properties from the object, you might need a more specific type, perhaps a union of several.

Comment: I am using an abstract method who return some data.
I definitly don't want to care about what is in that data, i just want to be sure that this data is a javascript object.
Thank you VLAZ this is what i am looking for, I will update the awnser ;)

Comment: [TypeScript Type Annotation Excluding Primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32187102)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VLAZ I have the awnser I was looking for : the type `object`.

I had some trouble to find it in typescript doc because *object* is not a revelant keyword to search for.

Her is the doc about it : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object